# Unable to install SonarQube Scanner CLI for java project in TFS

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, command-line-interface

I have downloaded the extension but unable to install it on my TFS 2015.Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2czp.jpg)

Comment: Does the error occur if you install the extension to other collection?

Comment: I just have one collection

Comment: Can you check if there is any error in the Event view of the TFS server?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the permission to install the extension. [Project collection administrators](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/add-administrator-tfs#project-collection) with [**Edit collection-level information permissions**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/permissions#collection) can install extensions.If you don't have the permission,please request it first, then try install the extension again.

If you already have the permission, just try to clean caches, close browser and reopen it,then try it again.

Please refer to [Get extensions for Team Foundation Server (TFS)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions#request) for more information.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for your response. But i have all the permissions and even after clearing the cache, i am getting the same error.

Comment: Also the error says: Sorry, we are having problems checking permissions and installation status. Give it few minutes and then please try again

Comment: @uttarabhosale You can try to restart the TFS Service, then try it again,there is a similar issue here for your reference.https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3117244/cant-install-extensions-acquisitionoptions-call-fails